# How are cost and reverse cost computed in pgrouting?

Tags: pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

I downloaded the nyc osm metro extract from Mapzen. I then used osm2pgrouting to import that data into postgis, pgrouting and now I have all these columns cost and reverse_cost, but I'm not sure how they were computed. I want to do a special form of routing by modifying the cost columns, but first I want to understand how these quantities were computed. Is it based on the length of the streets?

Comment: Welcome! Please edit your question to include more information. Where did you get the data? What have you done for research? Could you post a sample of your data? Please take the tour here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For osm2pgrouting V2.1:

- **length** is length of the segment in degree units
- **cost** and **reverse_cost** is the **length** in degree units. (include the negative values for wrong way)
- **length_m** is in meters (there is no cost_m or reverse_cost_m)
- **cost_s** and **reverse_cost_s** is in time: seconds units  (using the maxspeed value that is in km/hr transforming it to meters/second and using the **length_m**)

Comment: where did you find what these columns mean?